# Как вызвать переход на другую страницу вне action?

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

Использую `Axios` для запросов. Создал `interceptor` на ответ от сервера. Если сервер возвращает `401` ошибку, мне нужно взять `refresh token` и отправить на сервер что бы обновить `access token`.

Вот `interceptor`:

```
Axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    if(isResponseOK(response))
        return response;

    const originalRequest = response.config;

    Axios.post(REFRESH_TOKENS, {
        refreshToken: AppStore.retrieve("refreshToken")
    })
        .then(function (response) {

        })
        .catch(function (error) {

        });

}, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

И вот тут трудность. Если же проверка `refresh токена` прошла не успешно, мне нужно перенаправить пользователя на страницу авторизации. Как это сделать? учитывая что тут нет `store`, `dispatch` и т.д. В общем те штуки которые используются в `action` и т.д. Как это сделать?

Comment: spa приложение?

Comment: @ИльяПаймушкин да

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы планируете использовать axios + redux, посмотрите на https://github.com/svrcekmichal/redux-axios-middleware

В вашем случае вы можете повесить обработчик interceptors.response.success/error который уже имеет доступ к store и может диспатчить эвенты для изменения состояния.

```
 const middlewareConfig = {
    interceptors: {
      request: [{
        success: function ({getState, dispatch, getSourceAction}, req) {
          console.log(req); //contains information about request object
          //...
        },
        error: function ({getState, dispatch, getSourceAction}, error) {
          //...
        }
      }
      ],
      response: [{
        success: function ({getState, dispatch, getSourceAction}, req) {
          console.log(req); //contains information about request object
          //...
        },
        error: function ({getState, dispatch, getSourceAction}, error) {
          //...
        }
      }
      ]
    }
  };
```